# Xcode6 autogetters and autosetters

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Xcode6 ios swift

I have created my own class and trying to make an autogetter and autosetter, but i don't really know if it's allowed.

```
var Birthday:NSDate {
    get {return birthday}
    set(newValue){birthday = newValue}
}
var BirthYear:Int32 {
    get {}
    set {}
}
```

The last part of code triggers error, missing return, so my question is that - Is there any possibility to make getter and setter without making a second variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stored properties in swift are backed by hidden instance variables - the property itself is its own getter and setter, unless you implement it as a computed property, in that case you have to provide your own getter and/or setter. So when you write:

```
var birthday: NSDate
```

you use it as:

```
let value = classInstance.birthday
```

to read its value, and

```
classInstance.birthday = someDate
```

to assign a new value. You don't have to do anything special to make that work.

Suggested reading: [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368)

Side note: by convention variables and property should use lower camel case notation, so they should start with lowercase, and if made up of multiple words, make the first letter of each word in uppercase. For instance:

```
var single: Int
var multipleWordsVariable: String
```